# How to create a info view in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I had some textViews and image views in my app. On long pressing those views I need to show information regarding those views like in below picture.
[image]
In this picture on long pressing icon of overflow menu some info is displayed.

How can I create a custom info view like this. Any ideas please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of [Mihir Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68913220/16281582) is correct but according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/tooltips), it will only work from Android 8.0 (API level 26).

So if your app minimum SDK is Android 8.0 (API level 26) you can use

```
android:tooltipText="your message"
```

in your XML code.
Or use

```
view.tooltipText = "message"
```

in your java code.

But if you target API level below 26 you need to use

```
TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(view, "your message");
```

also make sure your gradle have `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'` this dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Just use tooltip

You can simply do this:
Edit: For API 26+

```
view.tooltipText = "message"
```

Now, when you will longpress on your view it will automatically display the "message".

Also, you can use custom view instead of the default one.